# Umbraco routes alongside normal mvc routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, umbraco, umbraco7

I have installed umbraco via nuget on a FRESH mvc5 project and i have a normal MVC controller.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Dashboard(RenderModel model, int? Id)
        {              
            return Content("ok");
        }
}
```

The problem is when i try to enter  /Home/Dashboard

i get this error: `No umbraco document matches the url '/home/dashboard'.`

How would i be able to have my mvc controllers co-exist with my umbraco.I am not interested in having umbraco documents and templates routing just have my normal MVC controllers work as if nothing has happened.I intend later to get contentby Id to use it in my mvc controllers.

Comment: For what you need Umbraco for then? Umbraco has it's own routing. You can read more about it here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/. You can hijack Umbraco routes and define your custom routes as well.

Comment: becauae i have a site and i added umbraco to it and i want my old routes functional.

Comment: You have all here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-routes

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco will not work with simple  controller you have to inherit with SurfaceController. As it works with Surface Controller like this

```
public class AccountController : SurfaceController
{
        public ActionResult Dashboard(RenderModel model, int? Id)
        {              
            return Content("ok");
        }
}
```

you can call this methode with following URL
/umbraco/surface/{controllername}/{action}/{id}

see documentation:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/surface-controllers

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. OP wants to use Umbraco routes mixed with custom routes to mvc controllers.

Comment: Then you should go with simple MVC5 project, Why you need Umbraco then?

Comment: See the above comments on the opening post. The poster wants to include Umbraco in an existing mvc application

Answer (score 0):

You can still use standard MVC controllers alongside Umbraco SurfaceControllers, you just have to keep in mind that Umbraco is handling routing, so you have to do your routing manually:

```cs
public class ApplicationEventHandler : IApplicationEventHandler
{
    public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        RegisterCustomRoutes();
    }

    private static void RegisterCustomRoutes()
    {
        // this is just an example, modify to suit your controllers and actions
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
           name: "WhateverController",
           url: "Whatever/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Whatever", action = "DoTheThing", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Then `WhateverController.DoTheThing(int id)` should be accessible at /whatever/dothething/1 , as it normally would for MVC.  Unfortunately if you have lots of controllers and actions this will probably be a lot of work to set up and even more to maintain, so you might need to find an easier way to generate these routes in bulk.